# In GCP Is possible move static IP address to another account? How?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, static-ip

I have two GCloud Accounts for two differents clients. Due to banking certification purposes I need to use a reserved static IP address in the other account.

Documentation only provides info about moving IPs between instances.

Comment: Did you contact Google support? I do not expect this to be possible without involving Google support.

Comment: I don't see any way to move IP's to another account.

Comment: Currently, it is not possible to migrate reserved static external IP address to another project. However, you can submit a feature-request to consider this option at google [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry, but it is not possible to transfer a public IP address. Maybe you can use a [shared VPC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc) or [network peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering).